# Pandas plot() without axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How to plot pandas dataframe without labels while using

```
df.plot()
```

Edit: I still want to keep the ticks labels

Comment: If you want to keep the "legend" `plt.legend(loc='best')`

make sure to plot the figure before .plot,  `plt.figure(); df.plot(); `

See 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization.html

Answer (score 1):

`df.plot()` returns a matplotlib Axes object, so use this to remove the axis:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
ax = df.plot()
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! i added some correction to my question that I want to keep the ticks labels not removing the labels entirely